# Unity play games services cloud save internal error

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-play-console, google-cloud-save

I have used the same code given by https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity to add the cloud save game functionality, enable save games have been called at the beginning of the code and save games are enabled from the google play console as well. The leaderboards and achievements are working fine.

The *OnSaveGameOpened* function gets an **internal error** as *SavedGameRequestStatus* status.
I am not able to find the cause of this (internal error being received as the status), can anyone help me out please? How can I solve this.

P.S. Serialized data (in the form of bytes[]) was fed into the *SaveGame* function, serialized using the binary formatter.

**Edit:**
I was able to debug this further, I get an error on the activation of save games in the play console. I have activated the save games feature and published it (this was done a few days ago). I have also confirmed that the Drive API, Play Games Services API and Play Games Management API are enabled under the API console project. I get following error,

*Cannot use snapshots without enabling the 'Saved Game' feature in Play console*

[log from running on an android mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2E3qI.png).

The answer to this question
[Google Play Games :: Cannot Use Snapshots Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725908/google-play-games-cannot-use-snapshots-exception) 
states that it will activate within 24hrs, but it is not active even after multiple days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved. It was not a problem from my end, it took well over 24 hours for the saved game services to activate. The problem solved itself once the saved games were enabled by google (there was no notification that the saved games were enabled, instead the app started working properly).

Answer (score 0):

There are several causes of an internal error; there should be other logs indicating the root cause. You might want to take a look into the source code to know what logs to expect.

If you're testing in an emulator, make sure your play services and play games are up-to-date.

Reference:
https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/blob/master/source/PluginDev/Assets/GooglePlayGames/Platforms/Android/AndroidSavedGameClient.cs

Comment: Thanks to you, I figured that a new version was available 0.10.09 (I was using 0.10.08). I was able to figure out more on what the error was but still I was not able to solve it. With the new version, it shows that 'Saved Game' is not activated in the play console. I am sure it is activated and it has been way over 24 hours since it was done.